# Which forecast is better- using restricted or unrestricted multivariate time series model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have 2 VAR(2) model of 4 dimensions (i.e. 4 TS)- Restricted and Unrestricted. Which model should be used for better forecasting?

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use **HoltWinters()** for univariate and **ar(),VAR()** for multivariate

Comment: Anyway I am using VAR only but which one I should use:
1) forecast(restrict(VAR(matrix,p=1)), n=5)
OR
2) forecast(VAR(matrix,p=1), n=5)